# NoMethodError in PrzychodyController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I encountered a problem while following the tutorial on the rails website: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html.
My names are different, but part from that I follow the tutorial. On step 5.7 I get an error like in the title saying:

```
undefined method `przychod_url' for #<PrzychodyController:0x000000000871c980> Did you mean? przychody_url
```

It shows that the problem is on the line:

```
    redirect_to @przychod
```

in przychody_controller.rb. I am new to RoR and Ruby or programing in general. I don't know what is causing this problem because the show action is present and is not made private like in some questions I found about this problem. Here is my routes.rb file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'welcome/index'

  resources :przychody

  root 'welcome#index'
end
```

That's the przychody_controller.rb file:

```
class PrzychodyController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @przychod = Przychod.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
  end

  def create
    @przychod = Przychod.new(przychod_params)

    @przychod.save
    redirect_to @przychod
  end

  private
    def przychod_params
      params.require(:przychod).permit(:tytul, :tresc, :kwota)
    end
end
```

And here is what my rake routes shows just in case it's something with routes:

```
 Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                                                              Controller#Action
                        welcome_index GET    /welcome/index(.:format)                                                                 welcome#index
                      przychody_index GET    /przychody(.:format)                                                                     przychody#index
                                      POST   /przychody(.:format)                                                                     przychody#create
                        new_przychody GET    /przychody/new(.:format)                                                                 przychody#new
                       edit_przychody GET    /przychody/:id/edit(.:format)                                                            przychody#edit
                            przychody GET    /przychody/:id(.:format)                                                                 przychody#show
                                      PATCH  /przychody/:id(.:format)                                                                 przychody#update
                                      PUT    /przychody/:id(.:format)                                                                 przychody#update
                                      DELETE /przychody/:id(.:format)                                                                 przychody#destroy
                                 root GET    /                                                                                        welcome#index
```

Thank you for your time in advance and I will be very grateful if someone could explain to me what is wrong and how to fix it or show me the solution.

Comment: Actually your `resources` routes must be named `przychodies` which is the pluralized version of `przychody` inferred by Rails. The error you're getting now (and yesterday) is because you "broke" that, and end up with resources routes but have to manually update them. Try updating the redirect to `redirect_to przychody_path(@przychod)`.

Comment: Your model name (I assume `Przychod`) can't be brought back to `przychody`. `'przychod'.pluralize #=> "przychods"` and `'przychody'.singularize #=> 'przychody'`

Answer (score 1):

It's broken due to rails pluralization rules. Rails by default uses english pluralization rules and working around them is painful, but possible.

For your case, you can tell rails how to pluralize that polish word in english code.

[Check this for details how.](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector/Inflections.html)

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect| 
  inflect.irregular('przychod', 'przychody')
end
```

After that rails knows and all the implied names that rails uses should work.

```
'przychod'.pluralize # => "przychody"
'przychody'.singularize # => "przychod"
```

Another option would be to not rely on rails  to  do any pluralization for you and  to always be  very explicit which path you want to go to.

```
redirect_to przychody_path(@przychod)
```

However, I suggest coding in english rather than making rails understand polish. Makes working with rails easier.